# Made a database in PGAdmin4 and unable to see database in command line in postgres

Tags: postgresql

In CLI whenever I try to view the database I do not see the database that I made with PGAdmin4 in postgres. It's just not there even though I see it in PGAdmin4. Curious how to troubleshoot

I need to be able to see this database I made in command line but am unable too see it.

Comment: Did you create that new database on the same database cluster? Please check your connection details. And how did you create a new database, please share the SQL statement that you used.